# Will this setup trip RCD or cause any issue?

Tags: circuit-design

I want to mix a function gen’s output with a 50Hz mains signal which is stepped down by a 24:1 transformer as follows:

[image]

Is this setup safe? A scope will monitor the composite signal.

Comment: It appears to be safe in some regards. What do you mean by safe?

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @Transistor That is not working on tablet I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live and neutral are completely isolated from the measurement circuit. What comes in on the live will return on the neutral so there will be no RCD current imbalance and it will not trip.